# C# IO Bound operations

Tags: c#, multithreading, io

I'm little confused about IO Bound  operations

Basically, I cannot find the best practices  For IO Bound operations.

For example, I have a bunch of requests that I need to send to remote servers 
20 requests for each I need to send post data and wait for response check that response and write it to log.

The Question Is What Should I use?

Should I create background Thread that will take of it?

Because I don't want to wait synchronously while all those requests will be completed. and partly because I don't care about them, they are just some logs etc.

Comment: you can use task in your project.

Comment: If you want asynchronous then use `await/async`.  Creating a background thread will still result in a synchronous call that just blocks a different thread.

Comment: Using a Thread makes the code simple since you don't have to write async code.  Nothing ever particularly wrong with simple code, especially when you have to ask this question.  If you want to write *optimal* code then the key is to *not* have a thread waiting for the I/O to complete.  But only use one when the I/O completes to process the response. Takes the usually painful BeginXxx() methods or the less painful async/await keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [async and await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)
..